# Get images with tag using FB's new Graph API for instagram

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

Recently, Instagram/Facebook stopped approving apps using their old Instagram API in favor of Facebook's graph api.

I'm struggling to figure out how to migrate of some of the functionality I'm wanting in my app.

With instagram, to get recent images with a given tag, you simply made a request to this URL:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Does the Facebook graph api for instagram have that? I couldn't find it in their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The new graph API does not support all the APIs that the old Instagram API supported. You cannot get images by hashtag and location and any user's posts, like you could with old APIs.

With new graph API you can only access your photos and your insights and comments.
No hashtag posts, other user posts, location posts or follower lists.

Comment: Is there a time-line for this support?

Comment: Instagram as not announced any support for hashtag API in Graph API

Comment: What about GPS?

Comment: no, with new Graph API, you can only get logged in users posts, comments, add/delete comments and get insights. You cannot get hashtag posts, location posts, geo search posts, cannot like posts, cannot get your followers or following or your liked posts.

Comment: @krisrak how make url for a call, say fetching my profile?
I am struggling in starting this

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal you can only get your profile using Graph API if it is a business account